# android setting EditText to scroll horizontally instead of vertically

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I am adding an editText control programmatically and the value of the control is longer than the width of the control and is wrapping onto the next line.
I want the text to read horizontally instead and not span multiple lines or allow vertical scrolling

I have tried multiple combinations of the following settings but they don't seem to affect it at all.

```
et.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
et.setSingleLine(true);
et.setLines(1);
et.setMaxLines(1);
et.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);

et.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT| InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_IME_MULTI_LINE);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove all, use only `et.setSingleLine(true);`

Comment: all i mean - et.setLines(1); et.setMaxLines(1);

Comment: there is another way: android:ellipsize="end" android:maxLines="1". And folowing methods: et.setEllipsize(); et.maxLines()

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    ll.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    EditText et = new EditText(this);
    et.setSingleLine(true);
    et.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    et.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT| InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_IME_MULTI_LINE);
    ll.addView(et);
    setContentView(ll);
}
```

Use only `setSingleLine(true);` this works fine.